# luis bot not speaking

Tags: node.js, botframework, text-to-speech, azure-language-understanding

I'm using the LUIS bot in NodeJS and I am using `session.say()` to get the bot the speak but there is not audio output. I am trying to say a list of movies from a list like this `session.say('hi', list.shift())` I know it works because 'hi' prints in the chat but no audio, I even put it in SSML format 
`session.say('hi','<speak version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/synthesis" xml:lang="en-US">hey</speak>');`

Any ideas why my bot isn't saying anything, but still printing stuff in the chat?

Comment: What if you add the following line `session.say('hi, this is a test','hi, this is a test audio');`

Comment: Didn't work, The 'hi, this is a test' showed up in my chat bot though

Comment: Which channels are you trying to use Speak in?

Comment: Not sure about that, how can I check?

Comment: Are you just using the Bot Framework Emulator on your local machine to test your bot, or are you testing it somewhere else like WebChat or Skype? Also, if you are using the Emulator, can you tell us which version you are using? You can check by either hitting the help dropdown menu item and selecting about or clicking the three dots in the top right corner of the chat, selecting settings, and then clicking about. It depends on what version you are using.

Comment: I am using the Bot Framework Emulator on on my local machine to test it. The Version is 4.1

Comment: Also, it looks like you are using V3 of the SDK. Is that correct?

Comment: One more thing, do you have a microsoftAppId and microsoftAppPassword for your bot?

Comment: no password or ID. Yes i am using v3

Answer (score 0):

To use the text to speech feature on the Bot Framework Emulator, the user has to use the microphone on the emulator first. Basically, the bot will only speak to the user if the user speaks to the bot first. Note, there are several steps you need to follow to enable the microphone feature on the emulator:

1. If you do not already have a microsoftAppId and microsoftAppPassword for your bot, you will either have to create a new bot or register your bot on the Azure Portal. Be aware that if you choose to register your bot, you will not be able to deploy it later without creating a new bot.
2. Once you have your microsoftAppId and microsoftAppPassword, you will have to create a `.env` file to store them. It should look like:

   MicrosoftAppId=YOUR_MICROSOFT_APP_ID
   MicrosoftAppPassword=YOURR_MICROSOFT_APP_PASSWORD

   Also, make sure you have configured the`dotenv` in your `app.js` file.
3. Now, you have to either add your microsoftAppId and microsoftAppPassword to the developer endpoint in your bot file or add it through the emulator. To add it in the emulator, right click on your bot under the `ENDPOINT` section and select `Edit Settings`. It should open a prompt where you can fill in the microsoftAppId and microsoftAppPassword.

Once you have completed all of the steps above, run your bot and connect to it in the emulator. You should be able to use the microphone to talk to your bot, and the bot should respond by speaking some text. Hope this helps.

Comment: which version of Bot emulator you used?? also which version of SDK to enable speak capability for your bot?

Comment: Also, Do we need to enable the Directline speech channel for this to work?